# Removing Sidebar from Pages & Post Permalinks

Tags: php, css, wordpress, sidebar

I am trying to remove the sidebar/widget area on my site beeandcompany.com.

However, I can't seem to do it. I've created a template file titled `no-sidebar-page.php`, uploaded that, and chosen it as the preferred page template for one of my pages (`/shop`), but it's still showing up.

I also added the following code to my CSS file to extend the page width for pages with no sidebar, but that's not working either:

```
.page-template-no-sidebar-page-php #content,
.page-template-no-sidebar-page-php .post {
  width: 960px;
}
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do, is to stop displaying the widget.

Literally. From your website, I see that the widget container id is 'masthead', so this should do the trick:

```
#masthead {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that is exactly it. So what do I do if I only want the masthead gone on pages and posts? (I still wanted the masthead to show on the homepage). And how do I extend the width of the content area on those pages and posts?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed

```
.page-template-no-sidebar-page-php #content, .page-template-no-sidebar-page-php .post { width: 960px; }
```

to
    .page-template-no-sidebar-page-php #masthead, .page-template-no-sidebar-page-php .post { width: 960px; }

And then I added another class to my style.css file

```
.site-content-fullwidth { float: left; width: 960px; }
```

Then in my no-sidebar-page.php template, I changed the "content-area" to the "site-content-fullwidth" class.